# decentralized counting of occurrences

Tags: software-design

I suppose using some sort of cryptography and other trickery it'd be possible to count how many occurrences have occurred.

for example suppose there is a way to identify each computer and my software is trying to count how many people have used it by connecting with each other which it does as it uses the internet.

so let's say my software is downloaded at computer A then so on...

like A>B>C...now the one at C need to know somehow that there are three unique computers that uses it.

and A>B>D needs to know it has also have three computers.

But if A>B>C>E and A>B>D>E now E needs to know there are 5 unique computers.

Now I could make system in which a unique id based on something (now what would that be) about computer gets stored in computer in array and software carries it with it and shares it with others whenever it is connected, then checks if there are new computers in array list so in end all know all others given enough connectivity.

However, from what I have learned from bitcoin and cryptography I have a feeling that there has to be another way beside storing a long string a million times (if there happen to be tons of computers).

Comment: A long string? Do you want each computer to know *how many* computers have run the code, or *which* computers have run the code?

Comment: how many but won't that mean they have to know which ones have because according to D and C there are total of 3 + 3 = 6 computers..but once you compare and eliminate duplicates it's actually 4. I was thinking like take guidOfCompX + nOtherCompsss into some crypto magic..will lead to something that will tell me in future that no this string contains like 30 guids that already belong to guids in your string...

Comment: Why not have *one* computer with a list, which distributes a number to all the rest?

Comment: why not have decentralized system.

Comment: Because it's more complicated. Do you want a decentralized system for robustness, or elegance, or the challenge of designing it, or some other reason?

Comment: I know it's more complicated, and harder path. But i want it to do it just theoretically yet. I think it will help me in understanding something else.

Comment: There are many possible approaches; without knowing what problem you're really trying to solve, I can't recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count how many have ever used the program?  Or how many are currently using the program?  Or how many have used the program within some amount of time before now?

If your count includes computers that are not guaranteed to be accessible (e.g. if counting unique computers that have ever used the program, or used it since some time but not necessarily online now), then it seems inevitable that you will need some centralized repository of the official accumulating list.  Each computer would need to communicate with that centralized list and pass it some unique identifier for the computer.  If you want to know computers since time T, tracking time information of the connections is also needed.

If you only want the number of computers that are currently using it (and accessible to each other), it might be possible for each one to interrogate the others dynamically at the point of time it wants to form a current count.  But even then, you would need some centralized convention for how they reach out to communicate.  Conceptually they are each dynamically joining a "set" and then leaving it again later.  Even if that "set" were not always located in a fixed single location, still there would need to be conceptually one official "set" and each instance would need to be able to connect with the "set" to join it and later leave it.  That implies a standardized point of contact and means of contact.

So I suspect what you might really want may not be quite possible in the way you were hoping.  That said, if you still want to think further about it, you might want to learn more about peer-to-peer software such as BitTorrent and others.

Comment: i'd say how many unique computers has it been installed at. I was wondering if it'd be possible, to do decentralized counting.